# How to log model using mlflow REST api? Does mlflow REST APIs support it?

Tags: machine-learning, mlflow, mlops

I'm writing a library using mlflow REST APIs.
I'm looking for mlflow REST api for logging different mlflow models.

In the doc, https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/rest-api.html#log-model it says the api will be removed in future and doesn't have description about model_json request body.

If I see github, https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/blob/master/docs/source/rest-api.rst mlflow REST API for Log model is missing.

Comment: Any reason why you wouldn't use the well-supported and documented python api?

Comment: Python api doesn't support authentication and authorisation. The mlflow tracking UI also doesn't have user based access. Hence i want to create a python library which uses my backend rest service to handle access mgmt which in-turn uses mlflow REST apis.

Comment: It supports personal access tokens.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on personal access token usage or provide some links, that would be really helpful.
Do you  mean mlflow tracking server url supports access tokens? And you can access only user related( based on personal token) information like runs, experiments in mlflow server?
or Do you mean personal access for backend artifact store? I need access management for metadata also like runs, metric/param logs, not just artifacts store

Comment: Sorry, I got confused. We use mlflow with Databricks and I confused Databricks tokens with mlflow. My bad.

Comment: No problem, Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score -1):

You can develop mlflow multi tenancy features for user level access to view models as per tenant.